# Microsoft Word - Antialiasing for font selection panel

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, anti-aliasing

Is there a way for me to **enable anti-aliasing on the Font Selection pane** in Microsoft Word? I know that there are other ways for me to search for fonts, but for a quick search the non-anti-aliased text makes it hard for me to see how the font actually looks on paper.

[image]

System-wide antialiasing has already been turned on, and my whole Word GUI (menus, text, etc.) is antialiased except this.

Comment: Option is to create custom add-in which will emulate this menu. If you know C# or VB.NET it's option for you.

Answer (score 4):

You may try the free [Font Finder](https://store.office.com/en-us/app.aspx?assetid=WA104211266&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&appredirect=false#0-2-0) add-on to Word.
It gets good notes, although it is not perfect.

[image]